# How to check if a responce of a CURL request is a file or HTML/Text before saving it in a variable? (PHP/CuRL)

Tags: php, ajax, post, curl

I am requesting a website like (Rapidshare)  that in response gives me either the requested file or some HTML telling that I need to wait xx seconds before I download file.
at 
I am confused how to code this scenario.

Now if I do posting using an HTML form, setting some fields in it and then auto submitting it using Javascript to the target site. If it is success, user is prompted with if he wants to download that fiel, and if it is fail for some reason like if user need to wait, it takes user to **THAT site** URL.

to avoid user redirecting to target site error page. I am using CURL, that sends POST request and reads response. 
Now, problem is, if reponse of CURL request is a file, page keeps loadin until and unless whole file recieved in response is download on server and stored in that variable.

this function That makes curl request at $url with $headerz as header values, and $encoded are request parameters

```
 function makeCurlPostRequest($url, $headerz, $encoded){
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       if($headerz!=null)
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerz);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       if($encoded!=null)
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
       $output = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
       return $output;
    }



 function checkUrl($file,$url,$headerz){
        $post_data = array ( "premium_acc" => "checked",
            "linkx" => "$file"
        );
        $encoded = '';
        foreach($post_data as $name => $value) {
          $encoded .= urlencode($name).'='.urlencode($value).'&';
        }
        $scrapHTML = makeCurlPostRequest($url, $headerz, $encoded);
        return $scrapHTML;
    }
```

CheckUrl, takes 3 parameters, $file link of file to download, $url url to request at and $headerz are header values.

Now I uploaded a test file

a.txt

with contents

ABCDABCDABCD

Then upon making a successful request and printing responce on Web browser using ti outputs this

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 08 Jul 2011
>   07:25:43 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.16
>   (Debian) X-Powered-By:
>   PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze1 Expires: Mon, 26
>   Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT Last-Modified:
>   Fri, 08 Jul 2011 07:25:43GMT
>   Cache-Control: no-cache,
>   must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Disposition: filename="a.txt"
>   Connection: close Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   Content-Length: 1 Content-Type:
>   application/force-download
>   ABCDABCDABCD

Where ABCDABCDABCD is contents ot TXT file. if it is an audio file it outputs some random characters after downloading it completely.

I need to prompt this data to user to download instead of first saving it on server or in a variable.

is there a way, I can check responce header if returned is a file and if a file then prompt user to download.

any solution by this CURL method?

OR

```
  <form action="d.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name ="url" value="<?php echo $url;?>"/>
     <?php 
     foreach($scrapHTML->find('input') as $field) {
      $name = $field->name;
      $value = $field->value;
     ?>       
            <input type="hidden" name ="<?php echo $name;?>" value="<?php echo $value;?>"/>
            <?php
     }
            ?>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            void(document.forms[0].submit());
    </script>
```

This HTML form sends request to target URL and on success prompts user with file to download but problem is in case of error it takes user to THAT website error or waiting page that I don't want to be visible to user.

Please provide a solution, either using curl or using HTML form post.

regards,
aqif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $opts = array ( 'http' => array ( 'max_redirects' => 1, 'ignore_errors' => 1 ) );
    stream_context_get_default ( $opts );
    $headers = get_headers ( $url, true );
    if ( strstr ( $headers [ 'Content-Type' ], 'text/html' ) ){
       ....... DO YOUR CODE ..........
    }
```

EDIT : Set this to send POST Variables

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
   stream_context_get_default ( $opts );
    $headers = get_headers ( $url, true );
    if ( strstr ( $headers [ 'Content-Type' ], 'text/html' ) ){
       ....... DO YOUR CODE ..........
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. sget_headers ($url, true) gets response header only but, this request donot includes post parameters, so it will always return html/text, I need to send file name as a parameter in post request. Simply I mean how to send parameters with get_headers function request

Comment: Thank you it worked like a charm :)
Can I have your MSN, Yahoo or skype if it is allowed here..

Comment: your welcome!:D it's my ids : hamid_udc@yahoo.com , hamid.udc@gmail.com

Comment: added you :) uncompressible is me